# Creating jquery menu - json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a bootstrap menu from a json response.  The menu gets the list of items and creates a link to https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/product_id which takes you to the json response.

What I need it to do is not follow the link to the json response, but rather get that response, parse the data and plug it into a div on the existing page, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/products/GetProductList/', function(data) {
        var output = '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        for (var i in data.Categories) {
            output += '<div class="panel-heading '+data.Categories[i].category_id +'"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#' + data.Categories[i].category_id + '-products">';
            output += data.Categories[i].Category + '</a></div>';
            output += '<div id="' + data.Categories[i].category_id + '-product" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body">';
            for (var j in data.Categories[i].Products) {
                output += '<li><a href="https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/'+data.Categories[i].Products[j].product_id+'">'+data.Categories[i].Products[j].short_description + " -- " + data.Categories[i].Products[j].cost+' coins</a></li>';
            }
            output += "</div></div>";
        }
        output += "</div>";

        document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = output;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a link to the product detail url, create a link to some function accepting the productid. 
This function could make a call just like the one you currently have for the product list, processing the json and appending the result to a div.

So add a function like:

```
function getProduct(id) {
    $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/' + id, function(data) {
        //Process JSON to some HTML.
        var productDetails = '<div>' + data.Product.Name + '</div>';
        //Add it to the div where you want your product details to appear
        document.getElementById("detailsDiv").innerHTML = productDetails;
    };
}
```

and replace the li, created for every product in the overview with something like the following:

```
output += '<li><a onclick="getProduct(' + data.Categories[i].Products[j].product_id + ');">'+data.Categories[i].Products[j].short_description + " -- " + data.Categories[i].Products[j].cost+' coins</a></li>';
```